# Python - Combine 2 rows into 1

Tags: python

I have a csv file which is a list as seen here:

A

B

C

D

E

F

And I would like to transform it into a list with pair like this:

AB

CD

EF

What is simplest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably to put each line of your file in a list and then create a list with half the size and your pairs. Since your `.csv` file appears to have only one column, the file format doesn't really matter.

Now, I assume that you have the file `eggs.csv` in the same directory as your Python file:

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
```

The following code produces the expected output:

```py
output_lines = []
with open('eggs.csv', 'r') as file:
  for first, second in zip(file, file):
    output_lines.append(f'{first.strip()}{second.strip()}')
```

If you execute this code and print `output_lines`, you will get

```
['AB', 'CD', 'EF']
```

Note that if the number of lines is odd, the last line will be simply ignored. I don't know the desired behavior so I just assumed this, but you can easily change the code.

Comment: A bit more "pythonic" and efficient is to avoid reading the whole file at once, and iterate it twice: `for first, second in zip(file, file):`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach using [itertools.islice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice), it will avoid reading the whole file at once:

```
import csv

from itertools import islice

CHUNK = 2


def chunks():
    with open("test.csv", newline="") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)

        while chunk := tuple(islice(reader, CHUNK)):
            yield "".join(*zip(*chunk))


def main():
    print(list(chunks()))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Note:**

The walrus operator (`:=`) is available since **Python 3.8+**, in previous versions you'll need something like this:

```
chunk = tuple(islice(reader, CHUNK))

while chunk:
    yield "".join(*zip(*chunk))
    chunk = tuple(islice(reader, CHUNK))
```